# Long text and opacity gradient mask

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, user-interface, user-controls

I have a `WPF/Silverlight` control - `200px` width. The problem is I want to place an item title on it, but I can't wrap lines. I thought that I can scale a font, but just found out that it's senseless, because those titles can be **VEERY** long. After few minutes I decided to do something like opacity gradient mask on the end 30 pixels of my control.

**E.g.** When I have a word `QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKL`, and the max substring that the control can show is `QWERTY`, then `TY`has an opacity gradient mask. When my mouse's pointer enters a region of my writings, the tooltip (or something) will be shown (whole text).

I have two questions:

1. What is the best way to realize such an opacity gradient mask?
2. How to show whole text after the mouse enters a text region (I think `ToolTip` is a poor solution)?

Comment: Why not simply set [TextTrimming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming.aspx) to `CharacterEllipsis`? At least that's the "standard" way to solve this problem. Also ToolTip is kind of a standard solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Well I don't know if you want to reconsider this approach. The much easier to achieve and probably more understandable way would be using ellipsis. Every user knows, when he sees such ellipsis, that this is only a part of the title.
   The `TextBlock` has such a built-in feature. Thanks to Clemens: `TextBlock.TextTrimming=CharacterEllipsis`
2. Why is a `ToolTip` a poor approach? If you don't like the way it looks like you could customize the style.

Comment: 1. Didn't know about `CharacterEllipsis` trimming:) Thanks.

2. It looks bad. Our team want our app to be an ideal:)

Comment: Btw. What's a solution for `Silverlight`? There's no `CharacterEllipsis` option for trimming prop.

Comment: Well according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) there is a text trimming option at least for the `TextBlock`.

Comment: Regarding to point 2: That's what I said. You need the functionality of a `Tooltip` control. If the appearance isn't good enough (and yes it's ugly ;o) ), you should customize the style. I hope you're using MS Blend, which is a great help for this job.

Comment: Don't know why (using `S5`), `WordEllipsis` doesn't exist for me:/

Comment: Hmm, ok. That's really odd. The [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.texttrimming%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) says, it's also supported in SL5. Perhaps you should check the project settings. Please note, that I changed `TextBox` to `TextBlock` in my post.

Comment: Hmm, don't know what's bad, but I checked project settings and everything seems to be ok. I also use `TextBlock`... :S But ok, I will write it myself. Good to know that there's something like these 2 options for trimming:) Thanks and have a nice day!